CSRF token not generated in django backend
I have a web application that I built using a Vuejs for the frontend and django for the backend. When I was developing the application, I did not have issues in regards to csrf token generation. I have only begin encountering this issue 2 months after development.
I am not sure why this issue is happening, or what was the behaviour for setting the csrf token when I was developing it. As far as I understand, an initial get request to the backend sets the csrf token in the browser, and can then be used by all other subsequent requests. But I do not see any csrf cookie in the applications tab.
I have this method for setting the csrf cookie in the backend:


def get_csrf_token(request):
    return JsonResponse({"detail": "CSRF cookie set"})



and this is where I call the method in my frontend:


onMounted( async()=>{  
  const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-csrf-token', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'  // This ensures cookies are sent with the request
    });
    console.log
    if (response.ok) {
        console.log("CSRF token set successfully.");
    } else {
        console.log("Failed to set CSRF token.");
    }    
})



this is my setting.py file if its needed:


"""
Django settings for api project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-6o!u*ed9z0#rrm9*2*t%ig#!^-yjm)%7g3m(!u+&ra_v+)*e%n'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

MEDIA_URL = '../../frontend/src/assets/Expert_imgs/'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://127.0.0.1:5173/','127.0.0.1']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://127.0.0.1:5173/',' http://127.0.0.1:5173 ','http://127.0.0.1:5173']

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://127.0.0.1:5173 ' ,'http://localhost', 'http://127.0.0.1:5173',  'http://localhost:5173','http://127.0.0.1:5173']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ace.it.notify@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'tqpn xdfm xhoy ihvm'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = BASE_DIR / "sent_emails"

#tqpn xdfm xhoy ihvm

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 600

LOGIN_URL= 'http://127.0.0.1:5173/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5173/'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'AceIt',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "auth.User"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'api.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'api.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'



I just want to know how to set a csrf token to be used in future requests.
